# How do i display in plot sum values that match a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have like a DataFrame with tables of diff values.
Suppose like i have this data

```
Fruits   Volume

Apple    120
Peach    340
Apple    400
Apple    21
Peach    45
etc...   ...
```

How do i group fruits up, so my plot would not look like picrelated?
[image: my outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try first sorting your dataframe by the column you want to group:

```
df = df.sort_values("Fruits")
```

and then when you plot (e.g with [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html)) specify the color based on the group:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df, x="label", y="Volume", hue="Fruits")
```